# Set local storage in a react Js method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a simple voting system (Yes or No) if you click Yes the state needs to be a string up and if you click No the state needs to be down, i need to set local storage in order to prevent the user from keeping voting, do i have to do this in useEffect or just in the **voteHandler** method, is there an alternative of the local storage ?

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import {AnswerContext} from './AnswerWrapper';

const AnswerItem = (props) => {

    let indexPlus;

    const indexCount = (index) => {
        indexPlus = index;
        return indexPlus;
    }

    const { active, setActive } = useContext(AnswerContext)

    const [vote, setVote] = useState();

    const voteHandler = (e, index, value) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem('myVoteInLocalStorage', value);
        setActive(index);
        setVote(value)
        // I am sending this to a parent component
        props.onVote ({
            vote : value,
            answerID : index
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index, 'up')}>Yes <span>({props.ups !== null ? props.ups : 0 })</span></button>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index, 'down')}>No <span>({props.downs !== null ? props.downs : 0 })</span></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AnswerItem;
```

Comment: *"i don't know how can i set the local storage"* - Have you tried anything at all?  What didn't work?  A cursory search on your favorite search engine for something like "javascript local storage example" is likely to find many examples to help you get started.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect? If you want user to not be able to vote again UNTIL he clears browsing data (or e.g. goes incognito mode) - `localStorage` or `cookie` is ok.
You have great example & docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: You've updated the question to include your attempt, but in what way is that attempt not working as expected?  How have you confirmed that this value isn't being set in local storage?  What's the actual problem that you're observing?

Comment: I can see the last value in the localStorage but the user can always vote